# Problem while editing a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i treid to edit one record of my tables in rails 3 but ann error occured like this :
**ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in WordsController#edit**
in my controller:

```
def edit
        @adverb =Adverb.find(:id)
  end
```

and in my view i have :

```
 <% @adverb.each do |av| %>
            <tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") -%>">
            <td><%= av.name  %></td>
            <td><%= av.bedeutung %></td> 
            <td>
            <%= link_to 'edit',{:controller => 'words',:action => 'edit',:id=> av.id} %>
            </td>
            </tr>
 <% end %>
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@adverb = Adverb.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1):

its just

```
@adverb = Adverb.find(params[:id])
```

You dont need the .first option on the end thats only needed when using the where statement

Answer (score 1):

`:id` is just a symbol, you are looking for that symbol's value inside the params hash

So instead of

```
Adverb.find(:id)
```

Use

```
Adverb.find(params[:id])
```

This will return a single record that matches the value of `:id` in `params` hash that is probably coming form you url `/adverbs/:id`

If there is no record with the provided ID, then an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception will be raised, which in development will show you a stack trace page, and in production will show a 404 page.